# When and why would I use Java synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'synchronized' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean)

What is the purpose of Java synchronization, and how should I use it?

Answer (score 13):

[Java Tutorial: Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). A generic answer to your generic question. Don't like it? Please elaborate a little. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to implement synchronization (as in Java), it is language dependent. Generally it can implemented using the OS level locks (as in semaphores, mutex etc)