# How to synchronize multithreaded app in one class, without worker threads and controller?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple threads which calculate the sum of a given array roughly speaking. I can't use separate worker threads and controller rather the whole program must be written in one class. The point of the program is to print the result of the calculation such that thread id 0 is the first to print the results, then thread id 1, then thread id 2, and so on in that order.

I wrote two synchronized methods in the class: `finished` - notify all threads once a particular thread finished the calculation and `waitForThread` - waits if threads with id's lesser than its own still haven't finished.

Because I can't use a separate controller class, I decided to create a static array `doneArr` in which each cell symbolizes a thread id and once a thread finished its job it updates the corresponding cell in `doneArr`. This way `waitForThread` knows when to wait.

I can't seem to get this to work, can you please point me to the right direction?

**EDIT:** the problem can be easily solved by using `join()` but I'm looking for a solution that uses synchronization.

This is the code:

```
public class WorkThread extends Thread {
    private int[] vec;
    private int id;
    private int result;
    private static int[] doneArr;
    private static int progress = 0;

    public WorkThread(int[] vec, int id) {
        this.vec = vec;
        this.id = id;
        doneArr = new int[vec.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < doneArr.length; i++) {
            doneArr[i] = -1; //default value
        }
    }
    private boolean finishedUpToMe() {
        for(int i = 0; i < id; i++) {
            if(doneArr[i] == -1)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private synchronized void waitForThread() throws InterruptedException {
        while(!finishedUpToMe() && id > 0)
            this.wait();
        progress++;
    }
    private synchronized void finished() throws IllegalMonitorStateException {
        this.notifyAll();
    }
    public int process(int[] vec, int id) {
        int result = 0;
        System.out.format("id = %d\n", this.id);
        for(int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
            vec[i] = vec[i] + 1;
            result = result + vec[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.waitForThread();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("waitForThread exception");
        }
        result = process(vec, id);
        doneArr[id] = id;
        System.out.format("id = %d, result = %d\n", id, result);
        try{
            this.finished();
        }catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
            System.out.format("finished exception\n");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vec = {1,2,3,4};
        WorkThread[] workers = new WorkThread[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            workers[i] = new WorkThread(vec, i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            workers[i].start();
        }
        System.out.format("main\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "the whole program must be written in one class" .... May I ask for the reason?  Why do you have to challenge yourself by posing such a strange restriction?

Comment: That is a very odd restriction. However, it shouldn't actually make much difference as you don't need a controller for such a simple task. If you really wanted one, you could simply use a thread pool or plain thread objects; they both take runnables or equivalent lambdas. Basically, instead of subclassing Thread like you have, you would just write your controller class and have it dispatch workers.

Comment: @user69513 this is what I'm trying to do, to write all logic inside `process` or `run` but my synchronization is out of whack.

Comment: @Yos I didn't look too carefully, but why does each thread initialize the static member `doneArr` separately?

Comment: @user69513 because I need some kind of global variable that will keep track of which threads finished their job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeatedly initialize the same static member, which while harmless here is a fairly bad practice. Instead, use a static initialization block to initialize static variables (not the constructor).

```
private static final int[] doneArr;
static {
    for(...) {...}
}
```

But of course, in this case you run into the problem that its length is variable. I also notice that `doneArr` contains ints, but you simply use it as a flag (ie -1 or !-1). So instead, use a `Map<Integer, Boolean>`.

```
private static final Map<Integer, Boolean> threadIsDone = new HashMap<>();

public WorkThread(int[] vec, int id) {
    threadIsDone.put(id, false);
    ...
}
```

Once you do this, while not strictly necessary in this particular case it is still good practice to protect against missing values when you are examining it.

```
private boolean finishedUpToMe() {
    for(int i = 0; i < id; i++) {
        final Boolean threadDone = threadIsDone.get(i);
        if (threadDone != null && !threadDone)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As for your threading issue, it seems that you used methods that are declared as synchronized. That's great for methods on a shared object, but that's not actually what you have - you have multiple unique worker objects. Because of this, you aren't actually synchronizing on the same object. This means:

- The JVM doesn't have to make writes visible to other threads.
- If writes do happen to become visible, you have a race condition.
- The call to `notifyAll()` doesn't actually accomplish anything.

Instead, use a lock object declared `static final`.

```
private static final Object lockObj = new Object();

private void waitForThread() {
    synchronized(lockObj) {...}
}

private void finished() {
    synchronized(lockObj) {...}
}
```

#### Edit: Other Thoughts

- Your code would be more readable if you declared variables closer to where they were actually used (ie immediately above the respective method).
- Your `process(...)` method is an instance method, but takes as arguments references to the instance variables that it already has access to.
- You should declare variables `final` if you aren't intending to modify them, for a [variety of reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/115702).

Comment: thank you for the feedback! I wanted to clarify regarding using `lockObj` would my  new `waitForThread` look like this: `private void waitForThread() {
    synchronized(lockObj) {while(!finishedUpToMe() && id > 0)
            this.wait();
        progress++;}
}`

Comment: @Yos Yes, but `this.wait()` also becomes `lockObj.wait()`. A synchronized method in Java is equivalent to a `synchronized(this) {...}` block [wrapping the entire method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11184735/9175160), and you are replacing `this` with the static member `lockObj`. And of course `this.notifyAll()` becomes `lockObj.notifyAll()`, etc etc.