# How do conventional locks protect from parallel access in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

One of the first things we all learnt about *concurrency in Java* is that we use **locks** (`synchronized keyword, Lock/ReadWriteLock interface`) to protect against *concurrent* access. For example:

```
synchronized void eat(){
        //some code
    }
```

In theory, this method `eat()` can be executed by a single thread. Even though there are many threads waiting to execute it, only one will take the **lock**. But then comes **parallelism**, which made me think twice about what I just said.

I have 4 core CPU. That means I can do 4 tasks *parallelly*. Yes, lock can be taken by a single thread. But could it happen that 4 threads call method `eat()` and take a **lock** at the LITERALLY same time, although there is a **lock** that needs to be acquired to actually do anything?

Can something like that even happen in Java? I guess it can't but I had to ask this. And how is it even dealing with a case I just said?

Comment: [You can actually have way more threads running than physical cores.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126154). And no, two threads can not obtain the [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) of the instance you're synchronizing on at once. Only one thread can do that - which is the magic of the keyword synchronized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Synchronization works in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184642/how-synchronization-works-in-java)

Comment: The _exact point_ of the `synchronized` keyword is to require the JVM to take specific measures to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Just to be sure that it has been understood: since `eat()` is an instance method, it can be executed by multiple threads when being invoked on different objects. Only threads attempting to invoke the method *on the same object* may block each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...4 threads...take a lock at the LITERALLY same time...

Can't happen. Any "synchronized" operation (e.g., "take a lock") must operate on the system's main memory, and in any conventional computer system, there is only one memory bus. It is physically impossible for more than one CPU to access the main memory at the same time.

If two CPUs *decide* to access the memory at literally the same time, the hardware guarantees that one of them will "win" the race and go first, while the other one is forced to wait its turn.

Comment: "while the other one is forced to wait its turn." but its turn will happen in a few nanoseconds. It is software level responsibility to resolve case when multiple threads are trying to get the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - JVM keeps a list of threads that are trying to get the lock.

More details

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Synchronization

Also, worth mentioning that list (aka "inflated lock") is only created when really required (== when contention on a lock happens).

Comment: "really required" is when contention on a lock happens.

Comment: That's what I meant. Updated the answer for clarity