# Swift: Creating iOS framework and importing the framework error : Variable used within its own initial value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I'm trying to build a iOS framework but at the moment I'm trying to import the framework I'm getting this error:

[image]

This is implementation of my framework:

```
public protocol myframeWorkDelegate{
    func doSomething(value:Int)
}
public class myframeWork{
    public var delegate:myframeWorkDelegate? = nil

    public func doingSomething(do:String){

    }
}
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you named your variable the name of your class. Swift compiler starts using the name of your variable right away, and decides that you are trying to read the value inside its own initializer, as in

```
var someVariable : String = someVariable
```

Of course, you are not doing this, so Swift compiler could distinguish between the two uses of `myframeWork` identifier in the declaration, at least theoretically. However, they decided it is not worth the trouble.

Renaming the variable or the class will fix this problem. You may also need to provide a public initializer for your class in order for the modified code to compile.

Comment: Please check my comment below

Comment: @user2924482 This is because you did not make a public initializer (they are internal by default, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224873/335858)).

Comment: but a protocol should need initializer

Comment: @user2924482 Class `myframeWork`, not a protocol, needs a public initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your `var`. The error is because the name of the class is the same as the name of the variable. Additionally, this is why you should always capitalize class names ie `class MyFramework` versus `var myFramework`.

Comment: I switch the name of my 'var' to 'var someframeWork = myframeWork()' but now I'm getting this error 'myframeWork initializer is inaccessible due to internal protection level'