# Store Dictionary to Struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am little bit stuck on conversion of Swift Dictionary to Struct data. Here is the API output I am getting.

[Response as Dictionary [String, Any]](https://pastecode.io/s/3gb40rvm)

Its first time I writing Chat Application in Swift Codebase.
I need help to fill the data in Struct class and use it for display over **MessageKit**

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let parentChat: [ParentChat]
    let total_rows: Int
}

struct ParentChat: Codable {
    let chat_time: String
    let created_at: CLong
    let sender_name: String
    let receiver_name: String
    let sender_type: Int
    let message: String
    let id: Int
}
```

I have taken help of this link :

[Help I have taken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29553096/6280156)

[image: Error Getting]

Comment: `parentChat` should be `messages` or you can customize it with `CodingKey`. What is the output now? Since the reference link could work.

Comment: Let me try, can you share the changes in more details. I will help me

Comment: Did you get the dictionary from a network response? Can you convert it to a struct directly?

Comment: Not directly, I am using Stackoverflow link

Comment: The CodingKeys in the screenshot are not related to the API output at all. This causes the error. And when you load the data from a server you can decode it directly to a struct.

Comment: @vadian, if you can share any code will be helpful, I am stuck from 2 day as my background is mainly from Android side more

Comment: Can you show more code where you get that `[String: Any]`?

Comment: @AnkitTale It will be more helpful if you share the code where the dictionary comes from.

Comment: copy and paste your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/ and it will generate the code for you.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out. I was stuck for 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my First API call written in Swift language for GET method. I am dropping code below for future help.

```
struct ChatResponse: Codable {
    let status: String
    let messages: [Message]
    let totalRows: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status, messages
        case totalRows = "total_rows"
    }
}

// MARK: - Message
struct Message: Codable {
    let chatTime: String
    let createdAt: Int
    let senderName: String
    let receiverName: String
    let senderType: Int
    let message: String
    let id: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case chatTime = "chat_time"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case senderName = "sender_name"
        case receiverName = "receiver_name"
        case senderType = "sender_type"
        case message, id
    }
}
```

For API Call GET method...

[Link TO GET Call](https://pastecode.io/s/rtkcq7hg)