# binary operator += cannot be applied to two Int operands

Tags: swift, struct, int

I'm creating a simple struct.

```
struct Expenses {

    var totalExpenses:Int = 0

    func addExpense(expense: Int) {
        totalExpenses += expense
    }
}
```

It produce error at the beginning of line `totalExpenses += expense`
The error message is

> binary operator += cannot be applied to two Int operands.

Why I am getting the error message and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam "How to solve this error?". Adding it right now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `addExpense` is a `mutating` function, like so:

```
struct Expenses {
    var totalExpenses:Int = 0

    mutating func addExpense(expense: Int) {
        totalExpenses += expense
    }
}
```

From the documentation:

> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the
>   properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance
>   methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or
>   enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating
>   behavior for that method.

For more information see *[The Swift Programming Language: Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)*

Comment: Thanks. What would you use in this case, then? A class?

Comment: If you used a class you wouldn't need to specify the method was `mutating`, but that's not a reason to use a class instead of a struct. I would recommend looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class

Comment: Thanks. My worry was that adding the 'mutating' keyword was somehow bad practice.

Comment: Its perfectly valid to use structs and `mutating`, I prefer it to using classes as you don't have to worry about memory leaks and such.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change struct unless you use mutating keyword, struct is not mutable by default, try this:

```
mutating func addExpense(expense: Int) { ... }
```

Comment: This could do with a better error message that mentions that "mutating" is needed. Well, the compiler is quite new...

Comment: @gnasher729 Exactly. I missed that part in the doc (first time programming) and I had no idea why I couldn't add two ints.

Comment: The compiler errors in Swift are pretty awful across the board. All they really mean is "duh, something's wrong...". It's up to you to go figure out what. Worse, sometimes the messages point you in completely the wrong direction. I feel like I'm using a C compiler from the early 1980s again.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue the other day, either use `mutating` keyword on your function or define your `struct` as `class` instead.