# How to Create inheritance for enum

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to create an inheritance for below enum

```
enum BankAuthError: String {
    case authFailed = "AuthFailed"
    case technicalError = "Unavailable"
    case accountLocked = "Locked"
    case unknownError = "UnknownError"
    case userInteractionRequired = "UserInteractionNeeded"
    case realmUserAlreadyConnected = "UserExists"
}
```

I am able to use this enum as below

```
let errorCode = BankAuthError(rawValue:errorMessageCodeString)
```

Now I am trying to create inheritance from above struct as below

```
//MARK:- Enum to handle all sysnc errors
enum SyncErrorStatus: BankAuthError {
 case usernameOrPasswordMissing = "UsernameOrPasswordMissing"
 case signatureMissing = "SignatureMissing"
 case twoPhaseAuthentication = "TwoPhaseAuth"
}
```

But if I am doing this, I am getting the compiler error as

> 'SyncErrorStatus' declares raw type 'BankAuthError', but does not
>   conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized

Please let me know whether can we create inheritance from above Raw enum or not.

Comment: Enums are value types, so they don't support inheritance. Possible duplicate of [Swift enum inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191532/swift-enum-inheritance)

Answer (score 6):

Enums are value types, so there's no such thing as inheritance for enums. When you declare an `enum` as `enum YourEnum: Type`, you declare the rawValue of your `enum` to be of type `Type`. However, `Type` needs to conform to `RawRepresentable`.

What you are looking for, to create an `enum` that contains all cases of another enum, plus some other cases in currently not possible in Swift. You cannot inherit all cases of an enum.