# Swift Constants file - class or struct?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to create a Constants file in my Swift project - filled with static let strings.

Should I create as a struct or a class? And why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a class you can create a subclass and obviously `override` `class` methods. If you are purely using `static` there is no difference at all.

If the properties are Value Types, `static if let someTypeProperty` will be fine. If they are Reference types some extra care is needed.

---

*Just some stuff with properties:*

```
struct PresetStringsStruct {

    static let someString : String = "Some Text" // struct
    static let someView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

    private init () {
        print("init") // never happens
    }
}

class PresetStringsClass {

    static let someString : String = "Some Text" // struct
    static let someView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

    private init () {
        print("init") // never happens
    }
}
```

---

**`struct` properties work as expected.**

```
// value properties
var txtStruct = PresetStringsStruct.someString // "Some Text"
txtStruct = "SomeOtherText" // "SomeOtherText"
var txtStruct2 = PresetStringsStruct.someString // "Some Text"

var txtClass = PresetStringsClass.someString // "Some Text"
txtClass = "SomeOtherText" // "SomeOtherText"
var txtClass2 = PresetStringsClass.someString // "Some Text"
```

---

**When the property is a `reference type` the static properties will return references to one instance.**

```
// reference properties
var viewStruct = PresetStringsStruct.someView
viewStruct.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
var viewStruct2 = PresetStringsStruct.someView // CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

var viewClass = PresetStringsClass.someView
viewClass.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
var viewClass2 = PresetStringsClass.someView // CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
```

---

**The only fool proof method that I know of is to use `static` functions.** You can obviously use `class` functions if you want to be able to `subclass` the `class` and `override` the functions. (`static` does not allow override and is actually an alias for `class final`)

**This also prevents too many Type Properties from remaining in memory** There is no way to get rid of a `static let someProperty : Int = 0`

```
struct PresetStringsStruct {

    static func someStringFunc() -> String {
        return "SomeText"
    }

    static func someViewFunc() -> UIView {
        return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    }
}

class PresetStringsClass {

    static func someStringFunc() -> String {
        return "SomeText"
    }

    static func someViewFunc() -> UIView {
        return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    }
}
```

---

**Then it is up to you to decide what makes more sense.** Since the enclosing `struct` or `class` is never used itself, it makes no difference. For me a `struct` makes more sense because I associate too much behaviour with `classes`.

---

You can also give yourself more work and get rid of the `()` that results from using functions instead of properties.

```
struct PresetStringsStruct {

    static var someString : String {
        get {
            return someStringFunc()
        }
    }

    static var someView : UIView {
        get {
            return someViewFunc()
        }
    }

    static func someStringFunc() -> String {
        return "SomeText"
    }

    static func someViewFunc() -> UIView {
        return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    }
}

var viewStruct = PresetStringsStruct.someView
viewStruct.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
var viewStruct2 = PresetStringsStruct.someView // CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use structs for static data is the best choice :

```
struct staticStrings {

    static let name = "String1"
    static let age = "age1"

}
```

And to access the data globally just call `staticStrings.name`.

**Why we use structs and its better than class:**
Structs are preferable if they are relatively small and copiable because copying is way safer than having multiple reference to the same instance as happens with classes.

For more details: [structs and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24232845/5035060)

Comment: When a class or a struct has only static properties / methods and will never be initialised it does not matter that the type itself is a Reference or Value type. It only matters how their behaviour influences the behaviour of their properties.

Comment: Well thats true @RMenke.