# Reuse large unchanged array in multiple swift classes without use of global variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm relatively new to iOS development, and yet this is a problem I just keep coming back to. In the last app I made, a high-school textbook definition review app, I had a large amount of text that was never changed. As use of global variables is frowned upon, I looked to alternatives like Singletons (how these would be more elegant eludes me, feels redundant), prepareForSegue (solves the issue, but it feels like there must be a better way) and permanent storage (makes no sense as the data is never altered, but it provides a central repository). Naively, I picked the latter, implementing a plist, diminishing performance.

My interpretation of use of singleton for this problem (in case my problem stems from misunderstanding):

```
class Global {
    let array = ["item1","item2",...,"item1042"]
}
```

Now I can access `array` from other classes by `Global.array`. My array is in fact a 3-dimensional array, however I don't see how that would change the issue (would have preferred to create a class, with many instances, but that felt like further complicating an issue simply for readability).

Aside from using coreData, which again seems like overkill, I'm at my wits end.

I want to use a single, unchanged array/dictionary throughout all my classes, preferably without copying it into every class.

What is the proper style to achieve this?

I apologise if this has already been answered (it seems to general not to have been), but whatever answers I found were either too complex for my level of understanding, or unhelpful.

Comment: If you want to use `Global.array` you have to write `static let array...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to `persist data` in a `single app session`. But, among all these, I prefer to create a variable in `AppDelegate` and use it in the app using a `shared instance`. 
This way you won't need to create a separate `singleton` or any other class with `static` `variable` or any kind of `global` `variable`.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    let array = ["item1","item2","item1042"]
    //....
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print((UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.array)
    }
}
```

Also, in case you want to `persist data` within `multiple app sessions`, you can use `UserDefaults`, `Core Data` or `File System`.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Comment: Sure..Upvote and accept the answer too. Happy coding..:)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
class Global {
    static let array = ["item1","item2",...,"item1042"]
}
```

Comment: I am aware this works, but is this the 'proper' way to do it? Edit: Can you explain how this is better than a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct to achieve this. Here is an example:

```
struct Constants {
  private init() {}

  static let array = ["item1","item2",...,"item1042"]
  static let exampleStringConstant = "exampleStringConstant"
  static let deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
  static let isRunningOnSimulator: Bool = {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && (os(iOS) || os(watchOS) || os(tvOS))
      return true
    #else
      return false
    #endif
  }()
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why would you use "deviceType", "deviceId" and "isRunningOnSimulator"

Comment: They are just constant value examples.

Comment: Yes i know that but why did you use them ?

Comment: Because I think they are commonly used.

For example, when you want to get device vendor id from anywhere in your codebase, you can use Constants.deviceId.

Comment: What is the advantage of a struct over a class in this example?

Comment: @MaxFest You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888654/swift-constants-file-class-or-struct