# How to cast a struct to Anyobject in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, class, casting

I have,

```
struct S {}
```

Along with,

```
func y (x: S) -> AnyObject {}
```

In Swift 2, is it possible to, within y(),

```
return x
```

My current code:

```
struct S {let value: Int = 0}
let x = S()
func y(x: S) -> AnyObject {return x}
```

Yields the following error:

> return expression of type 'S' does not conform to type 'AnyObject'

Is there a way to mitigate this?

Comment: Is there any reason why your struct can't be a class that conforms to `AnyObject`?

Comment: I use a struct here because I create several hundreds of them, and as such, making the struct a class would not only slow down my application, but also make it less efficient and more error prone. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class

Comment: I think you are reading too much into that discussion. Structs are value objects, which lets the compiler make some simplifying assumptions, but in the real world it's likely that you won't be able to detect the difference in performance. If you need a class object, (inheritance, need to pass by reference, etc.) then use one.

Comment: Alright, I changed it to a class and it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A `Struct` cannot conform to `AnyObject`. It can only conform to `Any`

Comment: Could I create a controller class that takes the struct that operates on the struct?