# Swift -> Struct or Class for the repository pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, architecture

I am building an iOS application in Swift.

The access to the data store is handled using a `Repository` which is a protocol.

Is it a good idea to use a `struct` for the implementation of the `Repository` or should it be a `class`?

What my concern is that, if the repository implementation is a `struct`, then copying a `Repository` on assignment might lead to several copies each having slightly different sets of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Choose Struct Over Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class)

Comment: Hi @RashwanL - This question is not a duplicate. Kindly read it. I've edited the title to make it clear

Comment: simple rule to follow: Use classes if you want reference types, use structs if you want value types :)

Comment: @suhit- I understand that. But in my specific case what should the repository implementation be?