# Swift: Classes are reference types?

Tags: swift

I wanted to know why can't you hold instances of a class in a variables -> why does it have to be a reference. That's a bit problematic because if I want to store a object in a two variables it any changes made to the object will change the values of my variables. Is there a way around it ?

thanks,

Comment: "*Is there a way around it*" – Yes, use value types. I would recommend having a read of https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 & https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID88.

Comment: Uhh... value types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use struct instead of class because structures pass by value

[Why Choose Struct Over Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class/24232845)