# Swift build time too long when the configuration is 'release'?

Tags: swift

I have a open source project and the counter of files in project are more than 40.

I build the project when the configuration is `Debug` and the compile time is `2m22s`.
And I also use the [BuildTimeAnalyzer](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode), the longest time of all is `28ms`.

But when I build the project with the `Release` configuration, it stuck in `Compile Swift source files` more than one hour.

I have no idea about this, please help me.

Comment: Please mention which Xcode version / swift version are you using?

Comment: I use xcode 8.2 and both swift 2.3 and swift 3.

Comment: Since it is an "open source project", could you provide the source of the project?

Comment: https://github.com/Pluto-Y/SwiftyEcharts, this one.

Comment: Have you measured build time with clean build or just build - maybe it is consuming derived data and hence fast build time?

Comment: @Miknash I'm sure that I had cleaned it.

Answer (score 2):

In the DEBUG build, if you add up all the time spent on each function, you get about 7s. The numbers don't quite add up — you have spent 142s to build the whole thing, but these functions just take about than 7s to compile??

That's because these timing just accounts for type-checking each function body. In the [Swift frontend](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a5fd009bf6952546c5094303fc123a169cc595bb/include/swift/Option/FrontendOptions.td#L155-L160) there are three flags you could use:

1. `-Xfrontend -debug-time-compilation`
2. `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies`
3. `-Xfrontend -debug-time-expression-type-checking`

Let's use the first to see the whole picture. Pick one slow file, say `Option.swift`, and look:

```
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
                               Swift compilation
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
  Total Execution Time: 30.5169 seconds (43.6413 wall clock)

   ---User Time---   --System Time--   --User+System--   ---Wall Time---  --- Name ---
  23.5183 ( 80.1%)   0.7773 ( 67.6%)  24.2957 ( 79.6%)  34.4762 ( 79.0%)  LLVM output
   3.7312 ( 12.7%)   0.0437 (  3.8%)   3.7749 ( 12.4%)   5.4192 ( 12.4%)  LLVM optimization
   1.8563 (  6.3%)   0.2830 ( 24.6%)   2.1393 (  7.0%)   3.1800 (  7.3%)  IRGen
   0.2026 (  0.7%)   0.0376 (  3.3%)   0.2402 (  0.8%)   0.4666 (  1.1%)  Type checking / Semantic analysis
... <snip> ...
  29.3665 (100.0%)   1.1504 (100.0%)  30.5169 (100.0%)  43.6413 (100.0%)  Total
```

Turns out it's not Swift that is slow, but LLVM! So there is not point looking at type-checking time. We can further check why LLVM is slow using `-Xllvm -time-passes`, but it won't give us useful information, it's just saying `X86 Assembly / Object Emitter` is taking most time.

Let's take a step back and check which files take most time to compile:

```
Option.swift             30.5169
Toolbox.swift            15.6143
PictorialBarSerie.swift  12.2670
LineSerie.swift           8.9690
ScatterSerie.swift        8.5959
FunnelSerie.swift         8.3299
GaugeSerie.swift          8.2945
...
```

Half a minute is spent in `Options.swift`. What's wrong with this file?

1. You have a huge struct, with 31 members. Compiling that struct alone takes 11 seconds.
2. You have a huge enum, with 80 variants. Compiling this enum alone takes 7 seconds.

The first problem is easy to fix: **Use `final class` instead!** The second problem would not have a simple fix (I don't see any time improvement with alternatives e.g. replace the enums with class hierarchy). All other slow files have a similar problem: large structure, large enums.

Simply replacing all `struct` with `final class` is enough to bring the compilation time from "over hours and still compiling" to "2.5 minutes".

---

See also [Why Choose Struct Over Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class). Your "struct"s may not qualify as `struct`s.

Note that changing from `struct` to class do change the semantics of users' code since classes have reference semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....
under `Build Settings` -> `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` for your `Release` choose `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Owholemodule`.  Then under `Other Swift Flags` enter `-Onone`.  Doing this carved off big chunks of time off my project.