# Does guard make a copy of variables in swift

Tags: swift, performance, memory

In swift you can unwrap optional values with a guard statement

`guard let foo = foo else { return nil }`

Is this statement making a copy of `foo`? In other words, could this statement be potentially expensive if `foo` is very large?

Comment: I'm curious, how would you use this knowledge? Suppose it did cause a copy, what would you do instead?

Comment: One example is that there are better ways of unwrapping if it is an expensive operation. In my case, I want to know if I should use a lock around this code since other threads are modifying `foo`

Comment: "One example is that there are better ways of unwrapping if it is an expensive operation" like what?

Comment: ```foo!``` wouldn't make a copy right? Or maybe it would be better to avoid an optional in the first place.

Comment: "`foo!` wouldn't make a copy right?" You don't know that. I mean, it happens not to, and neither does conditional binding, but I don't see that explicitly stated anywhere in the language docs. What would you do if they *did* cause copies? Your hands are kinda tied, you need this functionality, whether it causes copies or not.

Comment: Also, it's really rare for objects to very large. The only way a large object could exist, is to either have one object with *lots* of fields (thousands...), or a struct that composes together substructs, whose sizes all sum up. Most "large data" in an app is in dictionaries, arrays and other data structures which aren't stored inline. They're stored by reference, thus the object holding them only uses a machine word of RAM to "store" them.

Comment: My main question is whether foo is copied. As I mentioned my real goal is to decide if this statement needs a lock. In swift dictionaries are a value type, so ```let dictCopy = dict``` could be potentially very expensive as you are making a copy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194956/discussion-between-alexander-and-devin-haslam).

Answer (score 2):

Actually this depends on type of `foo` e.x `class` type won't create a copy unlike  `struct` type

`guard` isn't a magic keyword it simply `if not` presented in 1 word

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  guard let foo = foo else { return nil }
> ```
>
> Could this statement be potentially expensive if foo is very large?

Instead of asking yourself the question that way, ask it this way: what if you had said

```
if foo != nil {
    let foo = foo!
    // everything else here
}
```

Was saying `foo!` to unwrap the Optional "expensive"? Whatever your answer is, it must be exactly the same for `guard let foo = foo`, because they both do *exactly* the same thing: they test for `nil` and, if safe, they unwrap the Optional. And that is *all* they both do. The one is merely syntactic sugar for the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1- To only check if this foo does not equal nil
   In this case you can check if foo is nil or not

```
if foo != nil {
    // do you work here
}
```

2- To get information from foo
    In this case, you have to unwrap this optional (with guard-let or if-let statements) and here we have two cases:
    - if foo is a class, then it’s a reference type. so there will be no copy and a reference to this instance is created
    - if foo is a struct, then it’s a value type. so an entirely new instance is created (copied from the original)
    Also you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class) to see should you choose struct or class in swift

Answer (score 0):

If the property you're unwrapping is a reference type (e.g. a class) then no it will not make a copy, it will just create a new property with a reference to the original instance.

If the property you're unwrapping is a value type (e.g. struct) then it will make a copy.