# @State vs @ObservableObject - which and when?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm currently getting familiar with SwiftUI and Combine frameworks. And I'm not really getting the difference between these two approaches. When we have to keep track of some data (say, a list of tasks), we can declare a @State variable, and it's change will automatically send notification and update current view. However, it looks like it can also be done this way:

```
class TaskList: ObservableObject{
    //a list that's going to be modified and updated on different occasions
    @Published var list: [String]
}

class TodoListView {
    @ObservedObject var todoList = TaskList()
}
```

So, I missing a point - **how are @State and @ObservedObject approaches different and which one is preferable under which circumstances?**

Thanks!

Comment: Just follow origin [WWDC SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/frameworks/ui-frameworks?q=swiftui)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you mark any variables as `@State` in a SwiftUI `View` and bind them to a property inside the `body` of that `View`, the `body` will be recalculated whenever the `@State` variable changes and hence your whole `View` will be redrawn. Also, `@State` variables should serve as the single source of truth for a `View`. For these reasons, `@State` variables should only be accessed and updated from within the `body` of a `View` and hence should be declared `private`.

You should use `@State` when you are binding some user input (such as the value of a `TextField` or the chosen value from a `Picker`). `@State` should be used for **value types** (`struct`s and `enum`s).

On the other hand, `@ObservedObject` should be used for reference types (`class`es), since they trigger refreshing a view whenever any `@Published` property of the `ObservableObject` changes.

You should use `@ObservedObject` when you have some data coming in from outside your `View`, such as in an MVVM architecture with SwiftUI, your `ViewModel` should be stored as an `@ObservedObject` on your `View`.

A common mistake with `@ObservedObject`s is to declare and initialise them inside the `View` itself. This will lead to problems, since every time the `@ObservedObject` emits an update (one of its `@Published` properties gets updated), the view will be recreated - which will also create a new `@ObservedObject`, since it was initialised in the `View` itself. To avoid this problem, whenever you use `@ObservedObject`, you always **have to inject it into the view**. The iOS 14 `@StateObject` solves this issue.

Answer (score 8):

The main difference is that `@State` is for structs, and `@ObservedObject` is for classes. Both `@State` and `@ObservedObject` achieve a similar thing, of updating you when something changes.

A `struct` changes when some property has been mutated, which means that it gets recreated, therefore the `@State` is updated. A `class` updates `@ObservedObject` when a property is changed - using `@Published` to listen for changes. When either `@State` or `@ObservedObject` is updated, the view body gets remade.

The question you are really asking here is [when to use a struct vs a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28844400/9607863) if either would work in some situations.

In your case, since `TaskList` is only a basic data structure and doesn't require lots of properties you want to prevent from updating the view (by using/not using `@Published`), you should probably use a `struct` with `@State` instead.