# Splitting up an array and assigning values to each value in it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Im using Firestore and when I request data, it comes in an array

```
print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
```

which prints out
   `Document data: ["lastname": Test, "firstname": Test]`

```
I created a class 

    class User {

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {

        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}
```

How can I assign the part of the array for "lastname" to the `User` class and assign in to `lastName`

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do these parsings of Json to Model and vice versa is by using any parsing library e.g. [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper), [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) or swift's [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) protocol. You can do both way parsing with such an ease with them and even for complex data model you don't have to do a lot of work.
 So better not to reinvent the wheel.

Here are some examples for your specific usecase.

```
let userData = ["lastname": "Last", "firstname": "First"]
```

**Using ObjectMapper:** (*Install pod and add the import to get it work*)

```
struct User: Mappable {
    var firstname: String?
    var lastname: String?

    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
         firstname <- map["firstname"]
         lastname <- map["lastname"]
    }
}

if let newuser = Mapper<User>().map(JSON: userData) {
    print(newuser)
}
```

**Using Codeable protocol:**

```
struct User: Codable {
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
}

do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userData, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
["lastname": Test, "firstname": Test]
```

is a dictionary not an array , you need

```
guard let res = snap.value as? [String:String] ,let fname = res["firstName"] ,     
let lname = res["lastName"] else { return }
let user = User(firstName:fname,lastName:lname)
```

> Tip:think if you really need a `struct` not `class`

Comment: whats the benefit of a struct vs a class. I am going to try to implement the code u provided as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class