# Are Swift structs objects?

Tags: object, swift, struct

I know this is a basic question, but Structs in Swift are a lot more like objects than say, a C struct. Does that mean I should treat it as an object? Specifically I want to know if NSUserDefaults.objectForKey will work with a struct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [structure vs class in swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217586/structure-vs-class-in-swift-language)

Comment: how do you define object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different matters. Yes, Swift structs are very definitely objects - but that's *within Swift*. They are *not* the kind of object you can hand over to Objective-C!

Comment: It happens that I've just written a Swift tutorial that has a section on this very subject: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects