# Mapping class object using TranfsformType in ObjectMapper in Swift

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

I have a JSON as

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "cardTypeId": 1,
      "cardInfo": {
        "background": "#4267b2",
        "userName": "abkur_rt",
        "text": "Hello Video",
        "media": {
          "mediaUrl": "",
          "mediaType": "image",
          "mediaThumbUrl": ""
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "cardTypeId": 4,
      "cardInfo": {
        "text": "Image and text",
        "media": {
          "mediaUrl": "",
          "mediaType": "image",
          "mediaThumbUrl": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To Parse this i used ObjectMapper(https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper)
My query is that in my JSON i get `cardInfo` depending upon the `cardTypeId` So I made classes referring this link [ObjectMapper how to map different object based on JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269448/objectmapper-how-to-map-different-object-based-on-json) to understand how to make use of custom TransformType for classes. In the link's JSON reponse has Array but in my case if `cardTypeId` is 1 then there is 2 fields extra where as everything same in `cardInfo`. So i have made classes as below but i am not sure how will i create class inheriting TransFormType.

```
class LBDetailsList: Mappable {

    var lbListArray : [LBDetail]?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        lbListArray <- map ["data"]
    }
}
class LBDetail: Mappable {
    var cardTypeID : Int?
    var cardInfo: LBBaseCardInfo?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        cardInfo <- map["cardInfo"]
    }
}
class LBBaseCardInfo: Mappable {

    var text: String?
    var media: LBMedia?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        text <- map["text"]
        media <- map["media"]
    }
}
class CardType1: LBBaseCardInfo {

    var background, userName : String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        super.init(map: map)
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)
        background <- map["background"]
        userName <- map["userName"]
    }
}
class CardType2: LBBaseCardInfo {

    required init?(map: Map) {
        super.init(map: map)
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)
    }
}
class LBMedia: Mappable {

    var mediaURL: String?
    var mediaType: String?
    var mediaThumbURL: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        mediaURL <- map["mediaUrl"]
        mediaType <- map["mediaType"]
        mediaThumbURL <- map["mediaThumbUrl"]
    }
}
```

Please Kindly help me out to understand this framework.

Comment: In Swift 4+ all third-party libraries for parsing JSON into objects have become obsolete in favor of the `Codable` protocol. You are encouraged to drop `ObjectMapper` and use `Codable`.

Comment: Thanks for informing but i will have to go ahead with this for now and then change in near future for sure.

Comment: I would change right now. With `Codable` it's much easier to decode the different types

Answer (score 0):

You need to create in following way.

**1) BaseClass:**

```
struct BaseClass : Mappable {
    var code : Int?
    var status : String?
    var data : [CardData]?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        code <- map["code"]
        status <- map["status"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}
```

**2) CardData:**

```
struct CardData : Mappable {
    var cardTypeId : Int?
    var cardInfo : CardInfo?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        cardTypeId <- map["cardTypeId"]
        cardInfo <- map["cardInfo"]
    }
}
```

**3) Media:**

```
struct Media : Mappable {
    var mediaUrl : String?
    var mediaType : String?
    var mediaThumbUrl : String?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        mediaUrl <- map["mediaUrl"]
        mediaType <- map["mediaType"]
        mediaThumbUrl <- map["mediaThumbUrl"]
    }
}
```

**4) CardInfo:**

```
struct CardInfo : Mappable {
    var background : String?
    var userName : String?
    var text : String?
    var media : Media?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        background <- map["background"]
        userName <- map["userName"]
        text <- map["text"]
        media <- map["media"]
    }
}
```

I have created following Mappable structure based on your json. If your json haven't contains any keys then it will parse json with nil value.

For your `CardInfo` I have set `var text : String?` which means, If there aren't available this key, the json will be parse using nil. So when you use this, you must required to check not nil before unwrap.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: As you said If your json haven't contains any keys then it will parse json with nil value. This is what i dont want. I have almost 20 types i have only shown here 2 so if i use this approach i will have to add all those keys which are different in CardInfo class where then for each cards i will have variable having nil. I appreciate to try to help but this i approach i have already used and want to learn a new approach by using TransforType which is in ObjectMapper.

Comment: Because your JSON is not fixed, you can't assume it which one will come. You must required to add all keys.

Comment: Kindly check this link. This may give you idea what exactly i want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269448/objectmapper-how-to-map-different-object-based-on-json

Comment: Have you got solution using above link ? :)

Comment: I am unable to create a class similar to  `AnimalsArrayTransformType` as his example has keys different inside the Array where as in my case i have a class having different keys depending upon the cardtype. This can be achieved using that link but i am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer the question literally, but this is a *native* solution using `Decodable`.

It decodes the array for key `data` into an enum with associated values. This handles the different types very smoothly.

In the enum `cardTypeId` is decoded first and in a switch `cardInfo` is decoded depending on the type ID into the corresponding struct.

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    let code : Int
    let status : String
    let data : [CardData]
}

enum CardData  {
    case user(UserData), image(ImageData), unknown
}

extension CardData: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cardTypeId
        case cardInfo
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .cardTypeId)
        switch type {
        case 1:
            let info = try container.decode(UserData.self, forKey: .cardInfo)
            self = .user(info)
        case 4:
            let info = try container.decode(ImageData.self, forKey: .cardInfo)
            self = .image(info)
        default:
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}

struct UserData : Decodable {
    let text, userName, background : String
    let media : Media
}

struct ImageData : Decodable {
    let text : String
    let media : Media
}

struct Media : Decodable {
    let mediaUrl, mediaType, mediaThumbUrl : String
}
```

---

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "cardTypeId": 1,
      "cardInfo": {
        "background": "#4267b2",
        "userName": "abkur_rt",
        "text": "Hello Video",
        "media": {
          "mediaUrl": "",
          "mediaType": "image",
          "mediaThumbUrl": ""
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "cardTypeId": 4,
      "cardInfo": {
        "text": "Image and text",
        "media": {
          "mediaUrl": "",
          "mediaType": "image",
          "mediaThumbUrl": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let cardData = result.data
    for item in cardData {
        switch item {
        case .user(let userData) : print(userData)
        case .image(let imageData) : print(imageData)
        case .unknown: print("unknown")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This example will surely give me new opportunity to learn about `Codable` but i really want to know and learn how can i use TransforType of ObjectMapper.