# How to map Response Object to Alamofire 4.0 Post method

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hi i am new for swift programing language and i want to map Response Object using  **Alamofire** 4.0 POST method  for this i wrote below code but it's showing Exception like ObjectMapiing failed can some on help me please

### ViewController:-

```
let params = ["name": "admin",
                      "quantity": ""]

        Alamofire.request("Url",method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseObject {
            (response:DataResponse<Login>) in

            switch(response.result) {

            case .success(_):
                if response.result.value != nil{
                    print(response.result.value!)
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print(response.result.error!)
                break
            }
        }
```

### Login:-

```
 import UIKit
    import ObjectMapper

    class Login : Mappable{

       var CareInsYH:String?
    var CategoryYH:String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        CareInsYH <- map["CareInsYH"]
        CategoryYH <- map["CategoryYH"]
    }

   }
```

### Json Response:-

```
[
{
        CareInsYH = "";
        CategoryYH = "Type Stock GG - Gordyn        ";
        CollectionCodeYH = 0;
        CollectionsYH = "";
        ColourYH = "";
        CompositionYH = " ";
        ContinuityYH = "";
        CutQuantity = 0;
        DesignYH = "";
        ETAQuantity = 0;
        ExtraId = 14738;
        FRTestYH = "";
        HSCodeYH = "/img/Wash Care/Noimage.jpg";
        IDRPrice = 0;
        LightYH = 0;
        Location1YH = 0;
        Location2YH = 0;
        MartindaleYH = 0;
        MasterId = 14738;
        Name = "SAPPHIRE PTB 8902-1";
        POQuantity = 0;
        PillingYH = " ";
        ProductCode = "GG00787-01C";
        QtyOnHand = "97.72";
        RepeatYH = 0;
        ReservedQuantity = 0;
        RubbingYH = " ";
        SellingPrice = 625000;
        StatusYH = Stock;
        SupColourYH = "";
        SupDesignYH = "";
        SupplierCodeYH = "<null>";
        SupplierNameYH = 0;
        TotalAvlQuantity = "97.72";
        TypeYH = 0;
        USDPrice = 0;
        UsageYH = "";
        WashingYH = "";
        WeightYH = 0;
        WidthYH = "               ";
        WyzenbeekYH = " ";
        imageYH = "/img/products/SGG00787-01C.jpg";
}
]
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049260/4488252 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292779/4488252

Comment: what are those my problem is diff

Comment: when we map to object i am getting object mapping error

Answer (score 0):

JSON response is not correct, correct sample:

```
[ 
{
        "CareInsYH": "Pain Management",
        "CutQuantity": 0
    }
]
```

Copy your response to [JsonBlob](https://jsonblob.com/), it's wrong.

Comment: do you Import ObjectMaper?

Comment: what is the mistack can you please help

Comment: sure ok i will wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148984/discussion-between-hamed-akhlaghi-and-krish).

Comment: is this problem?

Comment: bjectMapper failed to serialize response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=ObjectMapper failed to serialize response.}

Comment: same problem that's not i think problem

Comment: This problem is for your JSON response, your code has not any problem

Comment: no no  i am doing mistake in android they integrated this fine

Comment: if want i will give you my tv details please see once