# Pass constant parameter by reference

Tags: swift, constants, pass-by-reference

How can I pass a constant parameter by reference?

In Swift it can be done just for variables (and using `inout` keyword).

Can I pass a constant by reference?

I want to do something like this:

```
let x = ["a":1, "b":2]
myFunc(&x)
```

Comment: *I want to do something like this:*  Why?  You never said why you want to do that.

Comment: Because `x` is very large.

Comment: So you're concerned that it is inefficient to pass a copy of `x` to the function?  Swift only copies on write, so the function will receive the original dictionary anyway.

Comment: But I don't want to modify `x`.

Comment: So you mean by default will `x` be passed by reference? But I think dictionaries will be passed by value, because the are not class. Am I right?

Comment: You're right. Dictionaries are structs and thus passed by value which implies that a copy is made.  Behind the scenes, Swift will do the efficient thing and not create a second copy of the dictionary.

Comment: @rick Being a reference or a value type is orthogonal to whether it is passed by reference or by value. Generally, arguments in Swift are always passed by value, unless passed with `&` (such as can be done with `inout` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` params). If you have a `[String: Int]` parameter, the dictionary you pass to it is passed by value. However, as I said earlier, `Dictionary` stores its keys + values indirectly in a reference-counted buffer (actually 2 buffers for native).

Comment: Simply passing a `Dictionary` by value does *not* copy those underlying buffers (only the pointers to those buffers!). Both the caller and the callee have a view onto the *same* buffers (they will take their own copy on a mutation taking place though – that's called copy-on-write). For this reason, you really don't need to pass the dictionary by reference.

Comment: I think I need more study. I know what are reference-counting and copy-on-write, but I didn't get you.

Comment: Thanks. I get you. You are so helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I pass a constant by reference?

Not that I'm aware of. However, you *should never* need to do so yourself.

In the specific case you raise with a `Dictionary`, you're dealing with a collection that stores its contents *indirectly*. At its simplest level, you can think of it as a structure that just has a single property, which is merely a reference to the actual storage for the keys & values of the dictionary.

Passing that struct, the dictionary, by value is equivalent to just passing a reference about. Multiple dictionaries can view the same key & value storage through that reference. However, a unique copy of the storage will be taken on mutation if necessary – this is called copy-on-write, and allows for value semantics without the overhead of copying the entire buffer every time the dictionary structure is copied.

So for that reason, there is absolutely no need for a pass-by-reference here. Just pass the dictionary normally (i.e by value – that is, not with `&` such as with `inout` and pointer parameters).

In the more general case of having a large structure that you want to avoid copying when passing by value to a function – the compiler already has you covered. It can perform various clever optimisations to reduce copying; one of which is passing the structure by reference to a function. I go into more detail about this [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43486408/2976878).

It's really not something you should need to think about unless:

- You actually need caller-side mutation (in which case, you want a `var` anyway).
- You've specifically identified a performance bottleneck (in that case, you may well benefit from making your own copy-on-write structure).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a `let` constant to an `inout` parameter.

According to [Swift reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545)

> In-out parameters are passed as follows:
>
> - When the function is called, the value of the argument is copied.
> - In the body of the function, the copy is modified.
> - When the function returns, the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument.

This automatically disqualifies `let` constants, because they cannot be assigned back.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know. So Swift cannot do it, yes?

Comment: @rick Correct. They even removed `var` in Swift 3, which killed a potentially useful case of caller-side mutation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You mean `var` parameters specifically, right? They didn't actually allow for caller-side mutation though, it was merely a mutable copy for the callee (in fact one of the reasons it was removed was due to being confused with the caller-side mutation behaviour of `inout`).