# is dictionary passed by value or reference

Tags: swift, dictionary

Attempting to change dictionary values in a lambda function and then expecting the updated values at the caller level.

```
let test = { (header: [String: Int]) -> Void in
    header.updateValue(header["width"]! * 10, forKey: "width")
    header.updateValue(header["height"]! * 10, forKey: "height")
}

test(header: ["width": 10, "height": 2])

print(header["width"]) // expecting 100
print(header["height"]) // expecting 20
```

Problem: It still shows 10 and 2 at the caller level.

Comment: By the way, it's much more natural to just use the subscript operator: `header["width"]! *= 10`

Comment: will it change the values at the caller level?

Comment: Nope. Dictionaries are structs, which are always passed by value unless explicitly passed by reference using the `inout` keyword. However, all mutating operations on a dictionary will trigger a copy of the data if there's a chance it can impact someone else. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493749/3141234 That post talks about `Array`, but COW is also implemented for `String`, `Dictionary`, and `Set`.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/5/10/inout-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are passed by value. You can declare the function as taking `inout Dictionary` if you need to update it in the caller, or you can capture it in the closure.

Comment: Thanks, help me with the syntax please for `inout`, i placed it before parameter type?

Comment: @Developer You'll have a bunch better experience learning Swift if you follow along a structured resource, rather than piecing parts together ad hoc. I'd recommend you start with the [language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)