# If I force unwrap a struct instance, does Swift copy it?

Tags: swift, optimization, struct, value-type, copy-on-write

If I force unwrap an optional instance of a struct, does Swift make a copy of it?

For example, in the following code, where `Point` is a struct, does Swift copy (internally) `point` when I unwrap it?

```
var point: Point?
point = Point(x: 0, y: 0)
print(point!.x)
```

Follow-Up Question

If not, then would

```
if point != nil {
  print(point!.x)
}
```

be more efficient than

```
if let point = point {
  print(point.x)
}
```

since I assume the latter code (due to the assignment) causes Swift to make a copy of `point`, correct??

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

> If I force unwrap an optional instance of a struct, does Swift make a
>   copy of it?

Not yet.

```
print(point!.x)
```

Actually means:

```
switch point {
    case .some(let _point): print(_point.x) 
    case .none: fatalError()
}
```

But Swift's architecture is copy **on write**. So so far there is no change, hence no copying happening

However if you do something like:

```
if var point = point { // notice the usage of `var` instead of `let`
    point.x = 5 // copy on write happened at this line. Because you just changed a property of `point` — assuming that `x` is a value type
}
```

Comment: Swift does **not** use a strictly copy on write behavior for arbitrary structs. Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486408/does-swift-copy-on-write-for-all-structs

Comment: @jtbandes woah. I didn't know of that. And not something I fully understand. Hence any reader should read my answer with CAUTION