# Difference between String and NSString in Struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been reading Apple developer document that `String` is a value type and `NSString` (`Foundation`) is a reference type, similarly `struct` is a value type but if I use `NSString` inside `struct` it's working like a `String.` Can you elaborate the difference?

Example:

```
struct testing {

    static var testingstring1 = NSString()

    static var testingstring2 = String()

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [structure vs class in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217586/structure-vs-class-in-swift-language)

Comment: NSString is class and String is struct

Comment: NSString is class and String is struct , I understand but  NSString is an reference type ,how it is working inside struct.

Comment: Hi Tj3n..it is not a duplicate question.Please understand my question.I did't ask the difference between structure and class.I'm asking the difference between data type declaration inside the    structure    .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is when you initialize the NSString, Swift is automatically changing it to a String. Try initializing the NSString like this and seeing if that gives you compile error:

```
    var testingstring1: NSString = "testingstring1" as NSString
```

Here is an explanation of the bridging between the two languages in terms of Objective-C's reference types and Swift's value types: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Answer (score 1):

**String is a struct**

// in Swift Module

public struct String

{

}

**NSString is a class**

// in Foundation Module

open class NSString : NSObject

{

}

Answer (score 0):

Swift is interoperatable with Objective-C and converts some Objective-C types to Swift types.

Types that can be converted between Obj-C and Swift are known as bridged types. String and `NSString` are example of such bridged types and hence you can assign `NSString` to a `String` variable.

Answer (score 0):

**String-NSString Mismatch:**

The NSString conception involves UTF-16 code‐ points. Each approach has its advantages. The NSString way makes for great speed and efficiency in comparison to Swift, which must walk the string to investigate how the characters are constructed; but the Swift way gives what you would intuitively think of as the right answer. To emphasize this difference, a nonliteral Swift string has no length property; its analog to an NSString’s length is the count of its utf16 property.
Fortunately, the element mismatch doesn’t arise very often in practice; but it can arise. Here’s a good test case:

```
let s = "Ha\u{030A}kon"
print(s.characters.count) // 5
let length = (s as NSString).length // or: s.utf16.count
print(length) // 6
```

We’ve created our string (the Norwegian name Håkon) using a Unicode code point that combines with the previous code point to form a character with a ring over it. Swift walks the whole string, so it normalizes the combination and reports five characters. Cocoa just sees at a glance that this string contains six 16-bit codepoints.