# Appending an object to an array of objects

Tags: arrays, swift

I get an unexpected result when I append a new object onto an array of objects. The append seems to overwrite the existing object in the array then append itself.

Any thoughts? Or am I missing something really simple.

Here's test code from my playground:

```
class myRecord {

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
     }

var myRecords = [myRecord]() 
var tempRecord = myRecord()


tempRecord.firstName = "John" 
tempRecord.lastName = "Brown" 
myRecords.append(tempRecord)

tempRecord.firstName = "Jane" 
tempRecord.lastName = "Doe" 
myRecords.append(tempRecord)

for x in 0..<myRecords.count {
    print(x, "=", myRecords[x].firstName!, myRecords[x].lastName!) }

Console output: 
0 = Jane Doe
1 = Jane Doe
```

Comment: yes because you kept changing the value of the same object which is `tempRecord`

Comment: what @Lamar said.  The array has an address to that object in memory. If you update the bytes of that object, the array still has the same address in to that object, what's at that address though has changed.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, changing from declaring a class to a struct gave me the results I expected. Copying the values into the array rather than passing them through as a reference made all the difference. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

This happens obviously because `class` are **Reference Type**. if your creating object of class that means your are creating memory reference of that `class`. And if you are changes property of that `class` that means your are changing the value of that reference in your memory heap. That why your last object (i.e Jane Doe) is replacing the value value of first Object(i.e John Brown).

So now in Array both elements refers same memory reference that why you getting both same object(i.e Jon Doe). If you changes implementation to `struct`, you getting answer as per you are implementing, Because struct are **Value Type**. So it refers only value of object.

To be more specify About class and struct Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217586/structure-vs-class-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace 'class' with 'struct' as class are reference type and struct are value type.

```
struct myRecord {

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
}

var myRecords = [myRecord]()
var tempRecord = myRecord()


tempRecord.firstName = "John"
tempRecord.lastName = "Brown"
myRecords.append(tempRecord)

tempRecord.firstName = "Jane"
tempRecord.lastName = "Doe"
myRecords.append(tempRecord)

for x in 0..<myRecords.count {
    print(x, "=", myRecords[x].firstName!, myRecords[x].lastName!) }
```

Comment: I did try this. But I keep getting this error "Editor placeholder in source file".  struct Step {
        let id = UUID()
      var count: Int
        var date: Date
    }
    
    var stepCount = [Step]()
    var tempStepCount = Step(count: Int>, date: Date)

Answer (score 0):

When you re-assigned the value of `tempRecord.firstName` and `tempRecord.lastName`, it overwrote the value at index 0 of the `myRecords` array to equal the new values you set.

Index 0 and Index 1 of the `myRecords` array both point to the same `tempRecord` class instance in memory which holds the value

`{
  firstName: Jane, 
  lastName: Doe
}`

In order to add multiple instances of the `myRecord` class, you could create a separate instance called `tempRecords1` and append the values to the `myRecords` array like so:

```
...

var tempRecord = myRecord()
var tempRecord1 = myRecord()

...

tempRecord1.firstName = "Jane"
tempRecord1.lastName = "Doe"
myRecords.append(tempRecord1)
```

Answer (score 0):

just put after

```
tempRecord.firstName = "John" 
tempRecord.lastName = "Brown" 
myRecords.append(tempRecord)

tempRecord = myRecords ()
```

then add jane doe.

you can use Struct instead of Class, depends on what you need.