# How to duplicate a custom object?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to duplicate a custom object. Is is possible without copying each and every field manually?

```
 var test1  = CustomerInfo()
 var test2 = CustomerInfo()
 test1 = test2
 test1.customername = "First"
 test2.customername = "Second"

 print(test1.customername) /* Getting "Second" , actually i want to get "First" */
```

Please suggest me any possible solution?

Comment: Yes you can do in this way like test2 = test1.mutableCopy()

Comment: getting crash on that line while trying to mutablecopy

Comment: This can only happen if `CustomerInfo` is a singleton. With a regular struct or class you'll get two different objects.

Comment: I can't see where you are copying your objects, your code is initialising 2 diferents objects is weird the result you are getting with this code, as @vadian says is your CustomerInfo a singleton class?

Comment: Can you post your CustomerInfo class?

Comment: What's `CustomerInfo` represents? a class or a struct?

Comment: @AhmadF its Class

Comment: @ReinierMelian sorry please check now, i have updated code

Comment: The added line `test1 = test2` is the crucial part of the question. Without it the question would make no sense.

Comment: @jan did you finally solve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
 func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = CustomerInfo(myIvar1: Type, myIvar2: type)//constructor or your class
        return copy
    }
 var test1  = CustomerInfo()
 var test2 = test1.copy as! CustomerInfo
```

hello Jan,

1. You need to confirm to the protocol NSCopying and implement the above copyWithZone: method .
2. Inside copyWithZone method just create the object using your constructor  method and return that object.
3. Whenever you want to copy just call copy on your exciting object.
   for complete reference follow this on apple official  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html

And if only Copy is main concern to your object  just use Structure instead of class as they are value type not reference type. Changing your class to structure  will make your type a value type but with lot of object oriented  limitations. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because class is reference type, you can use `struct` (value type) to do that

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217633/663663) is a really good example