# I am confuse structure vs class in swift language

Tags: swift, class, struct

I am confused about structure vs class. I have seen this example According to this example [structure-vs-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217586/structure-vs-class-in-swift-language) According to link may be code output is **15,15,15,20**

BUT code output is 
because Structure is not changed but when I have run code on Xcode it returns me **15,15,20,20**

```
class objectmanagement
{
    public var x : Int = 10;

    func display()
    {
        print("\(x)")
    }
}



struct StuctManagement{
    var obj = objectmanagement()
}


let SA = StuctManagement()
SA.obj.x = 15

var SB = StuctManagement()
SB.obj = SA.obj

SA.obj.display()
SB.obj.display()

SB.obj.x = 20


SA.obj.display()
SB.obj.display()
```

I am confused please help me to understand this output this is same as a class output

Comment: Classes are by reference and you have said that obj for SB is the same as the obj for SA. A class object still behaves like a class object even if it is a property of a struct. In the linked example the property is a struct (String) in the second part. This question should be closed as a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift `class` is reference type. (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10))

When you say:

```
SB.obj = SA.obj
```

It means that the object of SA is the exact object in SB. (there is one pointer for SA.obj and SB.obj)

Although

```
let SB = SA
```

makes copy of SA and create SB with different reference.

Comment: yes in an example struct type reference is not changed like this

struct S { var data: Int = -1 }
var a = S()
var b = a      // a is copied to b
a.data = 42      // Changes a, not b
println("\(a.data), \(b.data)") // prints "42, -1"

b.data is not changed , nut in my code when you run code on xcode it,s answer is changed

Comment: Mention that objectmanagement is class not struct!