# Newbie: referencing and initializing structure elements within structures

Tags: arrays, swift, structure, initializing

OK, super-newbie Swift learner here with what I am sure is a simple question, that for some reason I cannot wrap my head around.

In the below code, I am creating a (very) simple address book structure just to understand how to reference and initialize the various elements, especially structures within structures. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to write this? I am getting errors (using Swift Playground).

Errors on the last three lines:

> Instance member 'page' cannot be used on the type 'AddressBookStruct'
>   Instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type '[AddressPageStruct]'.

Plus, when I set `var page = [AddressBookStrcut]` I get the error:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Thanks in advance for the understanding nudge. :)

```
struct AddressPageStruct {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let cellPhone: Int

    init(f: String, l:String, c:Int) {
        firstName = f
        lastName = l
        cellPhone = c
    }
}

struct AddressBookStruct {
    let color: String
    let size: String
    var page = [AddressPageStruct]
}

var littleBlackBook = AddressBookStruct.self

littleBlackBook.init(color: "Black", size: "Little")

littleBlackBook.page[0].cellPhone = 6191234567
littleBlackBook.page[0].firstName = "Bob"
littleBlackBook.page[0].lastName = "Smith"
```

Comment: Please share your errors.

Comment: Errors on the last three lines:  "Instance member 'page' cannot be used on the type 'AddressBookStruct'" and "Instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type '[AddressPageStruct]'".   ----   plus, when I set "var page = [AddressBookStrcut]" I get the error "Expected member name or constructor call after type name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct is value type, please check this.
[structure vs class in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217586/structure-vs-class-in-swift-language),

you can't make this littleBlackBook.page[0].cellPhone,  because cellPhone is constant you use let, instead use the constructor, also I change the page for empty array of AddressPageStruct

```
import Cocoa

struct AddressPageStruct {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let cellPhone: Int

    init(f: String, l:String, c:Int) {
        firstName = f
        lastName = l
        cellPhone = c
    }
}

struct AddressBookStruct {
    let color: String
    let size: String
    var page = [AddressPageStruct]()
}

var littleBlackBook = AddressBookStruct(color: "Black", size: "Little")

littleBlackBook.page.append(AddressPageStruct(f: "Bob", l: "Smith", c: 6191234567))
print(littleBlackBook.page)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
    var littleBlackBook = AddressBookStruct(color: "Black", size: "Little")
    let item = AddressPageStruct(f: "Bob", l: "Smith", c:6191234567 )
    littleBlackBook.page.append(item)
    littleBlackBook.page.append(AddressPageStruct(f: "Joe", l: "Blog", c: 3123467))
    print(littleBlackBook.page[0])
    print(littleBlackBook.page[1])
    print(littleBlackBook)
```