# How to persist data using MVVM in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I’m practicing MVVM and SwiftUI by making a simple practice app. The main view of the app is a list where presents a title (in each cell) that can change by user input (text field). By selecting the cell, the app presents you the detail view where it presents another text.

I managed to change the cell´s title but I can’t figure out how to change the text in the detail view and make it stay that way. When I change the text in the detail view and go back to the main view, after entering again, the text doesn’t stay the same.

How can I make the text in the detail view maintain the text of whatever the user writes?

Comment: In your Sandwish.swift file you need to use an `@Binding` instead of an `@State` so that you are modifying the object passed to it not it's own state version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Sandwish` is a *struct* which means when you pass it around it's copied (See [structure vs class in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24217586/8697793)). This also means that when you pass a `sandwish`:

```
CPCell(sandwish: sandwish)
...
struct CPCell: View {
    @State var sandwish: Sandwish
    ...
}
```

a `sandwish` is copied - any changes you make on this copy will not apply to the original `sandwish`.

When you do `$sandwish.name` in `CPCell` you're already binding to a *copy*. And in the `NavigationLink` you're *copying* it again.

```
struct CPCell: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: SandwishDetail(sandwish: sandwish)) {
            TextField("Record", text: $sandwish.name)
        }
    }
}
```

So in the `SandwishDetail` you're already using a copy of a copy of your original `sandwish`.

```
struct SandwishDetail: View {
    @State var sandwish: Sandwish // <- this is not the same struct as in `ContentView`
    ...
}
```

One way is to make `Sandwish` a class. Another, maybe better, solution is to use `@Binding`.

Note that the change from `@State var sandwish` to `@Binding` is not enough. CPCell expects the `sandwish` parameter to be `Binding<Sandwish>`, so you can't just pass a struct of type `Sandwish`.

One of the solutions is to use an index to access a binding from the `SandwishStore`:

```
ForEach (0..<store.sandwishes.count, id:\.self) { index in
    CPCell(sandwish: self.$store.sandwishes[index])
}
...
struct CPCell: View {
    @Binding var sandwish: Sandwish
    ...
}
```

Also you should do the same for all other places where the compiler expects `Binding<Sandwish>` and you originally passed `Sandwish`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, your explanation is really detailed. I just have one question. Your answer fixes the title problem of the cells, so I tried the same logic to the SandwishDetai view. But when I change in my SandwishDetail view the state for binding, it causes an error in the preview: Cannot convert value of type 'Sandwish' to expected argument type 'Binding<Sandwish>'. How can I fix it?

Comment: @BytoH I updated my answer to include more details. In short: you need to pass a *binding* and not just a `sandwish` which is just a *struct*. You can get this binding from the `SandwishStore` as presented above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate the time you took to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@State` to `@Binding` in Sandwish.swift and in your `CPCell` struct in ContentView.swift