# Pure Swift concurrency

Tags: multithreading, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

All the libraries I have come across that provide Swift concurrency functionality either depend on an Objective-C library or are wrappers around the C based [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/). (iOS and OS X)

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a pure Swift concurrency library? No dependencies. Or if not how might we go about making one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift language doesn't have constructs to support concurrency yet. Rumor has it that those are going to be added to a future version of the language, but in the meantime, I don't think you can do this without OS support.

GCD makes for fairly clean concurrent solutions in Swift, since GCD blocks are Swift closures. It's not platform-indpendent, however. (At least not outside the Apple ecosystem.)

### Edit:

I guess you could write a concurrency library that would run on all POSIX-compliant OS's by using POSIX, but Windows isn't really POSIX-compliant, so that might not be a perfect solution either.

### Edit #2:

In Swift 3 the GCD interface has been cleaned up and made much more "Swifty". Now there is a Dispatch class, that has class methods to do the things that used to use global functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple abstraction of queue-based dispatching like this:

```
protocol OperationQueue {
    var suspended: Bool { get set }
    var operationCount: Int { get }
    func addOperationWithBlock(block: () -> Void)
    func cancelAllOperations()
    func waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
}
```

Then, on OS X (or any other Apple platform), you could use GCD directly:

```
extension NSOperationQueue: OperationQueue { }
```

And on all other systems, you could create your own implementations:

```
class POSIXOperationQueue: OperationQueue { /* implementation with pthread */ }
class Win32OperationQueue: OperationQueue { /* implementation with Win32 API */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [Swift 5.5](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.5-released/), Swift now supports concurrency with built-in language features such as `async/await`, Tasks, TaskGroups, Actors and Structured Concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Concurrency**

[[Concurrency vs Parallelism]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63744581/4770877)
[[Sync vs Async]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75225609/4770877)

[Official doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html)

> Swift has built-in support for writing asynchronous and parallel code in a structured way.

It is a kind of from Swift v5.5 iOS v15 and v13 backward compatibility

solves:

- callback hell
- error handling(using native `try/catch` mechanism)
- natural, straight-line code which is simple to read, write and support

High level structure:

- `await/async` markers for recognising async block and run it. You are able to use `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` and `withCheckedContinuation` inside callback to support await/async

  - await async func
  - await async let
  - await `Actor`)
- `Task` - create a concurrent environment in which `await/async` is allowed, it is stared immediately after creation, can be prioritized duting creation and can be canceled, has it's own lifetime as a result - current state. `Task.init(priority:operation:)` creates **unstructured concurrency**(doesn't have a parent task)

  - `Task Group` - allow to run parallel(more dynamic then `await async let`) tasks and all off them done - task group is finished. When you use `TaskGroup.addTask` or `await async let` creates **Structured concurrency** because it has explicit parent-child relationship between task and taskGroup
- [[`Actor`]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75137101/4770877) - share **mutable referance_type data** between `tasks` in a **concurrent** environment which prevents **Data race**

Example:

```
func runImageTask() {
    let imageSaver = ImageSaver()
    Task.init {
        do {
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_dark_color_272x92dp.png")!
            guard let image = try await self.downloadImage(from: url) else { return }
            try await imageSaver.storeImage(image)
            guard let transformedImage = try await self.transformImage(image) else { return }
            try await imageSaver.storeImage(transformedImage)
            
            self.showImage(transformedImage)
        } catch {
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
    }
}

func downloadImage(from url: URL) async throws -> UIImage? {
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    return UIImage(data: data)
}

func transformImage(_ image: UIImage) async throws -> UIImage? {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
            image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

            guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
                continuation.resume(with: .failure(NSError(domain: "context is nil", code: 1)))
                return
            }

            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(5)
            context.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
            context.drawPath(using: .stroke)

            let transformedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
             
            continuation.resume(with: .success(transformedImage))
        }
    }
    
}

func showImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    self.imageView.image = image
}

class ImageSaver: NSObject {
    var continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>? = nil
    
    func storeImage(_ image: UIImage) async throws {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(saveCompleted), nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func saveCompleted(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        let result: Result<(), Error>
        if let error = error {
            result = .failure(error)
        } else {
            result = .success(())
        }
        self.continuation?.resume(with: result)
    }
}
```

[[Kotlin Coroutine]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169350/4770877)