# What is the difference between a data race and a race condition?

Tags: parallel-processing, dependencies, race-condition

I have been reading about data races and race conditions, but it seems that these are used in place of each other.

So what is the real difference?

Comment: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/490

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are "data races" and "race condition" actually the same thing in context of concurrent programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276259/are-data-races-and-race-condition-actually-the-same-thing-in-context-of-conc)

Comment: Thanks, I did find that blogpost. But I still feel somewhat confused.
Specially about Race Conditions.