# Are Thread Safety and Data Race condition addressing the same issue?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, language-agnostic

I am confused. As I understand, a piece of code is [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261690/1977871) if it functions correctly during simultaneous execution by multiple threads. 
And [data race](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049303/1977871) occurs when 2 instructions from different threads access the same memory location, at least one of these accesses is a write and there is no synchronization that is mandating any particular order among these accesses.

Its clear that both relate to concurrency. But are they addressing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a program(or its part) has a *data race*, then there is very high probability that the program is *NOT thread safe*.

*Thread-safety* declares **ultimate** property for the program, which uses multithreading. But **checking** this property **is very difficult** task and cannot be *fully* performed automatically (because the term *correctness* in multithreaded case is badly formalized).

*Data race* declares event, which (relatively) **easy to check automatically**, and having this event has **high correlation** with *thread-unsafety*.

Summarized:

1. **No** *data race* - program **can be** *thread safe*.
2. *Data race* - program is **unlikely** *thread safe*.

---

Some languages *prohibit* to write programs with data races. For such languages:

1. **No** *data race* - program **can be** *thread safe*.
2. *Data race* - program is **never** *thread safe*.