# Would there be a practical application for a more memory efficient boolean?

Tags: memory, types, boolean

I've noticed that booleans occupy a whole byte, despite only needing 1 bit. I was wondering whether we could have something like

```
struct smartbool{char data;}
```

, which would store 8 booleans at once.

I am aware that it would take more time to retrieve data, although would the tradeoff be a practical application in some scenarios?
Am I missing something about the memory usage of booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally variables are aligned on word boundaries, memory use is balanced against efficiency of access. For one-off boolean variables it may not make sense to store them in a denser form.

If you do need a bunch of booleans you can use things like this BitSet data structure: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html.

There is a type of database index that stores booleans efficiently:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index. The less space an index takes up the easier it is to keep in memory.

There are already widely used data types that support multiple booleans, they are called integers. you can store and retrieve multiple booleans in an integral type, using bitwise operations, screening out the bits you don't care about with a pattern of bits called a bitmask.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of "packing" is certainly possible and sometimes useful, as a memory-saving optimization.  Many languages and libraries provide a way to make it convenient, e.g. [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) in C++ is meant to be implemented this way.

However, it should be done only when the programmer knows it will happen and specifically wants it.  There is a tradeoff in speed: if bits are used, then setting / clearing / testing a specific `bool` requires first computing a mask with an appropriate shift, and setting or clearing it now requires a read-modify-write instead of just a write.

And there is a more serious issue in multithreaded programs.  Languages like C++ promise that different threads can freely modify different objects, including different elements of the same array, without needing synchronization or causing a [data race](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276259/are-data-races-and-race-condition-actually-the-same-thing-in-context-of-conc).  For instance, if we have

```
bool a, b; // not atomic
void thread1() { /* reads and writes a */ }
void thread2() { /* reads and writes b */ }
```

then this is supposed to work fine.  But if the compiler made `a` and `b` two different bits in the same byte, concurrent accesses to them would be a data race on that byte, and could cause incorrect behavior (e.g. if the read-modify-writes being done by the two threads were interleaved).  The only way to make it safe would be to require that both threads use atomic operations for all their accesses, which are typically many times slower.  And if the compiler could freely pack `bool`s in this way, then every operation on a potentially shared `bool` would have to be made atomic, throughout the entire program.  That would be prohibitively expensive.

So this is fine if the programmer wants to pack `bool`s to save memory, is willing to take the hit to speed, and can guarantee that they won't be accessed concurrently.  But they should be aware that it's happening, and have control over whether it does.

(Indeed, some people feel that having C++ provide this with `vector<bool>` was a mistake, since programmers have to know that it is a special exception to the otherwise general rule that `vector<T>` behaves like an array of `T`, and different elements of the vector can safely be accessed concurrently.  Perhaps they should have left `vector<bool>` to work in the naive way, and given a different name to the packed version, similar to `std::bitset`.)