# MultiThreaded CrossValidation using java

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I'm using Java Threads to implement the Weka CrossValidation (10fold CV), but having difficulty understanding where the averaging part takes place in the method `EvaluateModel()`.

I need to make sure each thread has its own copy of the error rate for each fold, and then perform the averaging when threads finish execution.

Comment: Weka has option for 10 fold cross validation. Check this https://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+cross-validation+folds+(Java+approach)?responseToken=059d9097b76aea994da4b2ffe7affd507

Comment: yes but this doesnot provide enough details for how the ModelEvaluate method works. where exactly the division by the number of folds takes place in the (Evaluation class )

Answer (score 0):

From whatever you have described here is approach you must try in multiple thread concept.

You have to create thread which will accept your model and test dataset.

```
EvaluateThread t1 = new EvaluateThread(threadName,model,testDataset1);
EvaluateThread t2 = new EvaluateThread(threadName,model,testDataset2);
EvaluateThread t3 = new EvaluateThread(threadName,model,testDataset3);
```

Then create synchronized method so that each thread can access that method independently.

Something like this

```
public synchronized double calculateError(model, dataset){
       // do your stuff for e.g. calculate error
       return error;
}
```

Finally calculate average of error you get from each thread.
For more info about synchronized method check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679563/1540330).

Comment: Yes, thats what im doing, im implementing the Runnable interface, and in the Run method i added the crossvalidatemethod for weka, the last method in the Run is called EvaluateModel(), it return a double array for predicted Values called Predicted[]. im not sure whether this method does the averaging for the errors collected from each fold or not and what the values in that predicted array means !

Comment: Could you please post a small snippet so that I can understand more.

Comment: Okay to make it clearer, i created a new class called Eval_Thread and it implements the Runnable interface, inside the Run method of this class im doing the following  <code>   Instances train = data.trainCV(numFolds, i, random);
      setPriors(train);
      Classifier copiedClassifier = AbstractClassifier.makeCopy(classifier);
      copiedClassifier.buildClassifier(train);
      Instances test = data.testCV(numFolds, i);
      evaluateModel(copiedClassifier, test);

Comment: According you explanation you are getting the double array (double[]), and according to weka's documentation the double[] is the prediction which is done by the classifier http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModel(weka.classifiers.Classifier,%20weka.core.Instances,%20java.lang.Object...) Kindly clarify you want the error rate or cross validation parameters like precision recall. I am sure you are not going to average the prediction.

Comment: what im trying to do is to make each thread hold a fold, and does the work separately. and at the end collect the result obtained from each thread. so if the evaluatemodel method for weka does the averaging and return a predicted array, this means i can't use this method in my Run, meaning it cant be multithreaded

Comment: Simply im working to make a multithreaded version for WEka's cross validation, so i copied and modified the weka's version for cross validation so that if im doing 5 folds im using 5 threads one for each fold and return to main thread to print the output like F measure or any other metric

Comment: <code>  public void run() { inst = new Instances(inst);
          inst.randomize(rand);
      if (inst.classAttribute().isNominal()) 
         {inst.stratify(nf);
         }Instances train = inst.trainCV(nf,t_ID, rand);setPriors(train);copiedClassifier = AbstractClassifier.makeCopy(clas);copiedClassifier.buildClassifier(train);evaluateModel(copiedClassifier, test);<code>