# Data Structures in 2D-Games with Multiplayer (Java)

Tags: java, networking, arraylist, multiplayer

I have following problem:

I've programmed a 2D Game with a multiplayer function. Right now i store others Player Data and GameObjects in two **ArrayList** (The world is stored otherwise). Sometimes the Network-Thread sends Updates, which can not be applied, because the Game draws the Players/Game Objects (*java.util.ConcurrentModificationException*). Because this drawing process happens every Second around 60 times (because of animations) the problem apeers often (every 2 seconds). This is the code for the players ArrayList:

**Draw the Players:**

```
for (Player p : oPlayer) {
  if (p != null) {
    int x = (int) ((width / 2) + (p.x - getPlayerX()) * BLOCK_SIZE);
    int y = (int) ((height / 2) + (p.y - getPlayerY()) * BLOCK_SIZE);
    g.drawImage(onlinePlayer, x, y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, null);
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.drawString(p.getName(), x + (BLOCK_SIZE / 2) - (fm.stringWidth(p.getName()) / 2), y - 5);
  }
}
```

**Edit Information in Network-Thread:**

```
case "ADP": //add Player
  Game.oPlayer.add(new Player(message, id));
  sendX();
  sendY();
  break;
case "SPX": // set X
  for (Player p : Game.oPlayer) {
    if (p.getId() == id) {
      p.setX(Short.parseShort(message));
      break;
    }
  }
  break;
case "SPY": // set Y
  for (Player p : Game.oPlayer) {
    if (p.getId() == id) {
      p.setY(Short.parseShort(message));
      break;
    }
  }
  break;
case "PDI": // remove Player
  for (Player p : Game.oPlayer) {
    if (p.getId() == id) {
      Game.oPlayer.remove(p);
      break;
    }
  }
  break;
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is, that 2 Threads are working on the same list.
The first one is reading the List (`for (Player p : oPlayer) {`) and the second one is modifying it (`Game.oPlayer.add(new Player(message, id));`). This brings the oPlayer list into an (sort of) "inconsistent" state. Java sees that you modified something that you are reading and throws this exception to let you know, that something is not kosher.
More information about ConcurrentModificationExceptions can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

To clarify, you dipped into the so called [Readers-writer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem). You have an reader (Thread), that reads the Data of Game.oPlayer and a writer (Thread) that writes data to Game.oPlayer.

## Solutions

---

### Synchronized-Keyword

The `synchronized` keyword is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean). You would use it like this:

```
private final List<Player> players = ...;

public void addPlayer(Player player) {
    synchronized(players) {
        players.add(player);
    }
}

public void removePlayer(Player player) {
    synchronized(players) {
        players.remove(player);
    }
}
```

Note that the List has to bee final. Furhter i am using a local attribute instead of your static one. Remove `players` with `Game.oPlayer` to get a suited solution.
This allows only 1 thread to access `players.add()` and `players.remove()`.

---

### Lock

Informations about how to use Locks can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).

Easy said, you create a block like this:

```
try {
lock.lock();
// work ..
} finally {
lock.unlock();
}
```

so that only one thread can access the work part by saying `lock.lock()`. If any other thread locked the work part using lock.lock() and not unlocked it, the current thread will wait until `lock.unlock()` is called.    The try-finall block is used, to assure, that the lock is unlocked, even if your work part is throwing an throwable.

---

Furhter i would recommend itterating over a "copy" of the player-list like this:

```
List<Player> toIterate;
synchronized(players) {
    toIterate = new ArrayList<>(getPlayerList());
}
for(Player player : toIterate) {
    // work
}
```

Or synchronizing this part completly like this:

```
synchronized(players) {
    for(Player player : players) {
        // work
    }
}
```

The first one provides you with an copy of that instance, which basically means, it contains the same Objects as the original List, but it isn't the same List. It helps you by letting more threads work on there own "list" and finish theire jobs, regardless of updates at the current time, becaus the second example will block if:

1. Any thread wants to read the list.
2. Any thread modifies the list.

So you only have to synchronize the coppy part in the first example.

---

Even furhter (not particually part of your question, but still something that would make it easyer) i would recommend not using static, as you stated in `Game.oPlayer.[...]` and taking a look at [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

You could modify your Game-class to provide the methods `addPlayer(Player player);`, `removePlayer(Player player);` and `getPlayerList();` to realy code in an [Object Oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) fashion.
With that design, you could easyly modify your code, to handle the new concurrency issue.

Answer (score 1):

If a list is iterated or modified in one thread and also in another thread you will get a `ConcurrentModficationException`. In general user interface applications restrict modifying model data to a single thread, usually the user interface thread, such as the event dispatch thread of Swing, or the platform thread in JavaFX.

As an aside, for JavaFX there exists a [game library](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL) providing out of the box techniques for game development. JavaFX in general is much better suited for graphics intensive work than AWT or Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Vector instead? It is part of Collection and is synchronized.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: That is the answer to the question, why would it be a comment?

Comment: This is a solution, not an answer to the question.