# Why is this code not 'thread-safe'?

Tags: java, thread-safety

```
class ThreadUnsafe 
{ 
    static int  val1,  val2; 
    static void Go()
    { 
        if  (val2 != 0)  System.out.println( val1 / val2); 
        val2=0; 
    } 
}
```

Apparently the Go() method in this code is not considered "thread-safe". Why is this?

Comment: Because `val2` can change (by another thread) between `val2 != 0` and `val1 / val2`.  I'm not *entirely* familiar with the thread capabilities and conventions in Java, but what I'd probably do here is capture `val2` into a method-local variable and then perform the logic on that variable.

Comment: Or in another way: The check & access is not atomic.

Comment: There is also not synchronization for access to `val1` and `val2`. So first thread may not even know that one of the variables was changed in another thread.

Comment: If you are not updating val1 & val2 outside Go() method then you are unlikely to see any issues with multi-threading

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Java when concurrency is expected to be an issue either the `synchronized` keyword would be used on methods that change or read the internal state of the object or a `synchronized` block would be used with a lock on a non-null object. Both would require that accessor methods be created for setting the value of val1 and val2.

Example using synchronized on the methods that change (or read) internal state:

```
class ThreadSafe
{
    private static int val1;
    private static int val2;

    static synchronized void go()
    {
        if (val2 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(val1 / val2);
        }

        val2 = 0;
    }

    static synchronized void setVal1(int newVal1)
    {
        val1 = newVal1;
    }

    static synchronized void setVal2(int newVal2)
    {
        val2 = newVal2;
    }
}
```

In this case because the methods are static, the synchronization will occur on the class itself.

Example using synchronization on a non-null object:

```
class ThreadSafe
{
    private static int val1;
    private static int val2;

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    static void go()
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            if (val2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.println(val1 / val2);
            }

            val2 = 0;
        }
    }

    static void setVal1(int newVal1)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            val1 = newVal1;
        }
    }

    static synchronized void setVal2(int newVal2)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            val2 = newVal2;
        }
    }
}
```

See also [What does 'synchronized' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean)

Comment: @johnbanter the subsequent question you asked is insufficient to solve the concurrency problem because val1 and val2 can still be accessed outside the class. Without a modifier such as `private` those class variables are package private which means that other classes in the same package can modify them. Notice that I use the access modifier `private`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private