# Threadsafe access to variables

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to make an application ported to Java threadsafe and as such am looking to minimise the amount of static variables required.

I will show an example of an issue I want clarity on. I have a class `Eparams` as follows:

```
public class Eparams {
    private double a;

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

I set the value in another class, `Epi`.

```
public class Epi {

    static Eparams eparams = new Eparams();

    public void epi() {
        eparams.setA(3.44);
    }

    public Eparams getEparams() {
        return eparams;
    }
}
```

I want to access the value of `a` of type `Eparams` in another class, `EpiParts`:

```
public class EpiParts {

    public void test() {
        Epi epi = new Epi();

        Eparams eparams = epi.getEparams();

        double val= eparams.getA();
        System.out.print(val);
    }
}
```

I need `Eparams` values to be non-static and there are multiple threads accessing this class. Is the way I've done it the best way to achieve this?

If I declare in `Epi` a new instance of `Eparams` to be static, what are the implications of threads accessing this instance? Making this instance static was the only way I got it to work.

Is this the wrong way to go about this? Is there an easier way to retrieve values across different classes in a threadsafe manner (apart from function arguments and return values)?

Comment: you probably want to synchronize the access to `a`

Comment: you might want to take a look at [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). You could provide synchronized methods for accessing (getters) or altering (setters)  instance variables

Answer (score 2):

> If I declare in Epi a new instance of `Eparams` to be static, what are the implications of threads accessing this instance? Making this instance static was the only way I got it to work.

`static` doesn't make a member thread-safe in any way, just simplifies access to it via the class name.

> Is this the wrong way to go about this?

Yes, now the access to `a` isn't secure at all.

The options I would suggest here:

1. Using `synchronized` accessors.
2. Using an [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) variable with the [`Double.longBitsToDouble(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)) and [`Double.doubleToLongBits(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) conversions for the getter and setter respectively.

> Is there an easier way ... ?

Consider the first method, it's simple and strict.

Answer (score 1):

The structure you have is not really thread-unsafe because it won't actually crash or do very strange thing under multi-thread/heavy load.

The only issue you have is that multiple threads accessing `a` may see stale values. The simplest answer to that is to make `a` **volatile**.

```
public class Eparams {
    // Volatile to ensure `happens before`.
    private volatile double a;

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class Epi {
    // No escape will happen here.
    Eparams eparams = new Eparams();

    // Note that this is never called - is that deliberate or should this be a constructor?
    public void epi() {
        eparams.setA(3.44);
    }

    public Eparams getEparams() {
        return eparams;
    }
}

public class EpiParts {

    public void test() {
        Epi epi = new Epi();

        Eparams eparams = epi.getEparams();

        double val= eparams.getA();
        System.out.print(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. epi() is called directly from main() (for this demo example)

Answer (score 0):

The part with the `static Eparams eparams` should not play a big role. The only way the threads could interact with each other, is while accessing the members of `Eparams` itself, e.g. setting the value of `a`.

This altough can be easily solved by using the `synchronized` keyword on the `getter` and `setter`:

```
public synchronized double getA() {
    return a;
}

public synchronized void setA(double a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

> More on `synchronized` can be found in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean).

Comment: Yes I  considered adding synchronized keyword but this would not be fitting with the application I am building. Multiple threads need access and making getters/setters synchronized would add an too much time lag for the applications purpose.

Comment: @arsenal88 that is the only way tough. If you want consistent data you *have to* synchronize somewhere, else you'll get collisions and inconsistencies very fast

Comment: @Lino Synchronized is not the only way of thread-safety, final values and copies are some other examples. @arsenal88 Note that `synchronized` does not automatically make your code thread-safe, it just restricts other threads from entering the synchronized block at the same time. Eg. if something reads `Eparams.a` then immediately another thread sets `Eparams.a` to a new value, is the value that was first read still valid?

Comment: @xtratic of course but in the example from OP `final` values don't make sense that's why `synchronized` access should be used. But I agree that `immutability` is probably most times preferred

Comment: I only see `Eparams` being set to a literal value `eparams.setA(3.44);` so it's possible that `final` could work for OP. As for synchronizing, what benefit does it actually provide in this case? Synchronizing on each method separately means one could be reading at the same time another is writing. Why even synchronize them if that's how you're going to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Epi {
    static Eparams eparams = new Eparams();
```

`Eparams` being static means that all `Epi` instances are referencing the same `Epi`. Thus if `Epi` instances are running in different threads and updating `Eparams.setA()` then you'll have a problem.

My recommendation when multi-threading is to **use final variables wherever possible**. If `Eparams` was immutable then you'd be thread safe. Does the value in `Eparams` actually need to change from its initial value? If not, then I'd do something like this instead.

```
public class Eparams {
    final double a;
    public Eparams(double a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public double getA(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

When you *do* need something mutable and shared between threads then make sure it is synchronized or atomically updated and document that the value may be modified by multiple threads and may change at any time.

Also be sure about what you are exposing with your interface: With `public Eparams getEparams()`, do you really want to give `EpiParts` the reference to the `Eparams` that the `Epi` instances are sharing? Doing this means that `EpiParts` can now call `Eparams.setA()` and get in on modifying the value too.

I would go with something like the following. Hopefully its close to what you're going for:

```
// immutable is thread-safe
// make all fields final to make `Eparams` immutable
public class Eparams {
    private final double a;
    public Eparams(double a){ this.a = a; }
    public double getA(){
        return a;
    }
}

public class Epi {
    // shared between all instances of `Epi` but is immutable
    // also final so that nothing swaps out a new `Eparams` unexpectedly
    // which would be thread-unsafe
    private static final Eparams eparams = new Eparams(3.44);

    // it is safe to give strangers a reference to your immutable field
    /** Eparams is a constant */
    public static getEparams() {
        return eparams;
    }

    // if `Eparams` were mutable then be careful about giving 
    // it to strangers and instead do something like this
    /** Eparams is mutable and shared between `Epi` instances
        it's values may change at any moment, be careful.. */
    public static getEparamsA() {
        return eparams.getA();
    }
}
```