# Java Concurrency in Practice "Listing 7.1. Using a volatile field to hold cancellation state.". synchronized for visibility?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice and encounter the following code snippets. I think the usage of `synchronized` is for visibility (let the thread calling `generator.get()` see the latest `primes`), because the task `PrimeGenerator` is executed by one single thread and the internal `primes` is not shared with other threads.

Am I right?

> Listing 7.1. Using a volatile field to hold cancellation state.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class PrimeGenerator implements Runnable {
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final List<BigInteger> primes
            = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    private volatile boolean cancelled;

    public void run() {
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (!cancelled) {
            p = p.nextProbablePrime();
            synchronized (this) {
                primes.add(p);
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }

    public synchronized List<BigInteger> get() {
        return new ArrayList<BigInteger>(primes);
    }
}
```

> Listing 7.2. Generating a second’s worth of prime numbers.

```
List<BigInteger> aSecondOfPrimes() throws InterruptedException {
    PrimeGenerator generator = new PrimeGenerator();
    new Thread(generator).start();
    try {
        SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } finally {
        generator.cancel();
    }
    return generator.get();
}
```

Comment: Apparently so. Is there anything else that's unclear about it? I don't think SO allows us to give an answer of "Yes."

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, just want to make sure my understanding is right. Sorry for asking such a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the usage of `synchronized` has two purposes.

1. **Visibility**. Let the reading thread see the latest `primes` changed by adding threading.
2. **Atomicity**. When the reading thread is reading, the adding thread is blocked, and vice versa.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34261294/12284870
Also, section 3.1.1 ("Stale Data") of this book (i.e. Java Concurrency in Practice) affirms this as a way to ensure visibility.