# JVM hang suddenly with jdk version 8u1.8.0_312

Tags: java, jvm, freeze, arm64, g1gc

Our online Kafka Broker service suddenly hung up, and it's occurs with low probability and without any time regularity. no crash, no warning, no error and no logs

The command "`jstack [pid]`" no response, then I print the stack trace with command "`jstack -m [pid]`", and I found all threads state are **BLOCKED**, include **VM Thread**.

VM Thread stack:

```
ox0000ffff99f4da8c __pthread_cond_wait
ox0000ffff997c014c _ZN2os13PlatformEvent4parkEv
ox0000ffff9976f014 _ZN7Monitor5IWaitEP6Thread1
ox0000ffff9976faf0 _ZN7Monitor4waitEblb
ox0000ffff999355dc _ZN20SuspendibleThreadSet11synchronizeEv
ox0000ffff99858a68 _ZN20SafepointSynchronize5beginEv
ox0000ffff999d3124 _ZN8VMThread4loopEv
ox0000ffff999d3458 _ZN8VMThread3runEv
ox0000ffff997b8204 _ZL10java_startP6Thread
ox0000ffff99f47800 start_thread
```

Only one thead state is IN_NATIVE, it's stack trace:

```
ox0000ffff99de7dd8 __GI___poll
ox0000fffed7871a3c NET_Timeout0
ox0000fffe786ec40 Java_java_net_PlainSocketImpl_socketAccept
ox0000ffff8c015628 * java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) bci:0 (Interpreted frame)
ox0000ffff8c008498 * java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) bci:7 line:409 (Interpreted frame)
ox0000ffff8c008498 * java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(java.net.SocketImpl)
ox0000ffff8c008498 * java.net.ServerSocket.accept()
ox0000ffff8c008380 * sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept()
ox0000ffff8c008380 * sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop()
```

I'm not sure whether this is a JVM bug. Maybe IN_NATIVE thread is useless, STS call synchronize() stuck.

Linux on aarch64, and jdk version is
openjdk version "1.8.0_312" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-b07) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)

I try to find out the reason, but the JVM hang

Comment: It's a deadlock: not a JVM bug but a bug in your code.

Comment: @Pino i do not think it's a deadlock in my code. first, the jstack not detected deadlocks; second, the VM Thread stack trace is not normaly, it's stucked in `SuspendibleThreadSet::synchronize()`. VM Thread should not be stuck here even if deadlock exist.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611314/does-this-stack-dump-indicate-that-i-have-a-deadlock

Comment: However without the complete output of `jstack` some useful detail could be hidden.

Comment: application has 100+ threads, and all threads are BLOCKED. The oracle document:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/troubleshoot/troubleshoot-process-hangs-and-loops.html#GUID-88307E36-5BA7-4EF7-B90D-5B8F028E7890

Comment: Your link is interesting.  It also says [If the thread dump is printed and no deadlocks are found, then the issue might be a bug in which a thread is waiting for a monitor that is never notified.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/troubleshoot/troubleshoot-process-hangs-and-loops.html#GUID-8B8DE8E0-D7E3-48A9-96EB-77BC1128100D:~:text=If%20the%20thread%20dump%20is%20printed%20and%20no%20deadlocks%20are%20found%2C%20then%20the%20issue%20might%20be%20a%20bug%20in%20which%20a%20thread%20is%20waiting%20for%20a%20monitor%20that%20is%20never%20notified.)

Comment: I raised a question for JDK, and Martijn Verburg reply: https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/912

Comment: A deadlock is a specific situation where two (or more) thread wait for each other. It’s perfectly possible to have a hanging application without a deadlock, for example, just one thread waiting for an impossible condition. So far, you just have a hanging application and not shown any indicator for a deadlock nor for your assumption that this must be a bug in the JVM rather than a bug in your application.

Comment: @Holger My application is Kafka broker, it has 100+ threads.  The state of each thread is BLOCKED,  and each thread's stack is different. What's JVM hang?   Every   thread stopped, just like Stop The World.  If all threads waiting for an impossible condition, why VM Thread(GC generally) stuck in `SafepointSynchronize::begin()`

Answer (score 0):

it is seemed like a JVM bug, if it's a deadlock, the command "jstack [pid]" should be responsed.