# Java deadlock question

Tags: java

can anyone explain me why there is a deadlock in this code.Thanks

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", 
                    this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not always cause a deadlock. If thread 2 starts after thread one finishes then there wont be a deadlock. A Thread.sleep between the two thread startups avoids deadlock

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to wrap my wee brain around how threads deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749641/trying-to-wrap-my-wee-brain-around-how-threads-deadlock)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how it probably will be executed.

1. Enter `alphonse.bow(gaston);`, alphonse is now locked due to `synchronized` keyword
2. Enter `gaston.bow(alphonse);`, gaston is now locked
3. Can't execute `bower.bowBack(this);` from first `bow` method call because gaston (bower) is locked. Wait for lock to be released.
4. Can't execute `bower.bowBack(this);` from second `bow` method call because alphonse (bower) is locked. Wait for lock to be released.

Both threads wait for each other to release lock.

Answer (score 27):

Consider the following:

- Let *Thread1* `run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }`
- Let *Thread2* `run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }`
- *Thread1* enters `alphonse.bow(gaston);`, locking `alphonse` since `bow()` is `synchronized`
- *Thread2* enters `gaston.bow(alphonse);`, locking `gaston` since `bow()` is `synchronized`
- In *Thread1*, `bower.bowBack(this);` evaluates to `gaston.bowBack(alphonse);`

  - *Thread1* attempts to obtain the lock for `gaston`, currently held by *Thread2*
- In *Thread2*, `bower.bowBack(this);` evaluates to `alphonse.bowBack(gaston);`

  - *Thread2* attempts to obtain the lock for `alphonse`, currently held by *Thread1*
- each thread is waiting for the other to release a lock, hence deadlock

The problem is that there is excessive `synchronized` currently. There are many ways to "fix" this; here's an instructive solution:

```
    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", 
                    this.name, bower.getName());
        }
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
    public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
    }
```

Now `bowBack()` is fully `synchronized`, but `bow()` is only `synchronized` partially, using the `synchronized(this)` statement. This will prevent the deadlock.

Here are quotes from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 67: Avoid excessive synchronization*

> To avoid liveness and safety failures, *never cede control to the client* within a `synchronized` method or block. In other words, inside a `synchronized` region, do not invoke a method designed to be overridden, or provided by a client in the form of a function object. From the perspective of the `class` with the `synchronized` region, such methods are *alien*. The class has no knowledge of what the method does and have no control over it. Depending on what an alien method does, calling it from a `synchronized` region can cause exceptions, deadlocks, or data corruption.
>
> [...] As a rule, you should do as little work as possible inside `synchronized` regions. Obtain the lock, examine the shared data, transform it if necessary, and drop the lock.

In essence, `bower.bowBack(this)` is an attempt to cede control to an *alien* method, because `bowBack()` is not a `final` method in `class Friend`. Consider the following attempt to fix the problem, for example:

```
    // attempt to fix: STILL BROKEN!!!

    public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", 
            this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
        // ceding control to alien method within synchronized block!
    }
    
    // not a final method, subclasses may @Override
    public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
    }
```

The above code will not deadlock with the current `alphonse/gaston` scenario, but since `bow()` cedes control to a non-`final` method `bowBack()`, a subclass can `@Override` the method in such a way that will cause `bow()` to deadlock. That is, `bowBack()` is an *alien* method to `bow()`, and thus should *NOT* have been invoked from within a `synchronized` region.

#### References

- [JLS 8.4.3.6 `synchronized` Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6)
- [JLS 14.19 The `synchronized` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.19)
- [JLS 17.1 Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.1)

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition*

  - *Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*
  - *Item 15: Minimize mutability*

Answer (score 1):

Best way to understand is put below code in bow() before calling bower.bowBack

```
try {
Thread.sleep(1);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: in bow() method before calling bower.bowBack() method