# Why would this example from Java's documentation, cause a deadlock?

Tags: java, thread-safety, deadlock

I found this example of code that is likely to cause Deadlock on [Oracle's official Java site.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**Can someone explain why it is likely to cause Deadlock?**

When the first friend ("Alphonse") is `run`, it executes `bow` and also calls `bowBack` on the other friend. Somewhere while this is happening, the second friend ("Gaston") is run, it executes its own version of `bow` and calls `bowBack` on Alphonse. So where is there a deadlock? They are both calling their own versions of methods.

Comment: Googling for "alphonse gaston" will give you a handful of answers :)

Comment: Even older duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749641/trying-to-wrap-my-wee-brain-around-how-threads-deadlock

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry I didn't think of googling Alphonse, Gaston. Didn't realize how famous they were